# In my view page source, there is a weird box with 00 16 causing my image not to show in facebook sharing

Tags: php, html, yii2

In my yii2 project, when I use this `Yii::$app->urlManagerFrontEnd->baseUrl`, it shows this weird box in view page source code causing my sharing of image in og facebook not working, does anybody have any idea about this sign?

[image]

Comment: you are mixing different types of encondings,  probably UTF8 with something else.  If you are coding in windows it is probably set in some iso or some other default coding and the page is probably in utf8

Comment: Those are non-printables (the browser can't render them) so they are displayed as a box with the hex code of the item. How they got in your source code is up to you to find out.

Comment: how are you generating the meta tag can you add the specific code ? also your `urlManagerFrontEnd` configurations through which you are using the `baseUrl`

Comment: @JuanDiego any byte with a value less than 127 would not be subject to an encoding mismatch between UTF8 and any single-byte latin charset, and 0x16 is well inside of that way down in the control codes section. I am genuinely confused as to how those bytes would find their way in there.

Comment: @Sammitch have you tried changing the encoding on your browser to see what characters are those.  Using firefox https://superuser.com/questions/765044/how-do-i-view-a-page-with-a-different-character-encoding-in-firefox?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa. Are your php files, your server and your meta tags on the same encoding?

Comment: @JuanDiego `0x16` will *never* be a printable character, nor part of a valid multibyte UTF8 sequence.

Comment: sorry, you are right i didnt see that it was a 16

Comment: Can you show the context of the code? like the yii code were you call the base url

Comment: its probably an issue with the string construct